# How to rewrite url in .htaccess if the pointer is also a variable pointing the variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Rewrite in `.htaccess` for the URL:
`http://localhost/name.php?**category**=$origin&gender=$gen&alpha=$alphabet`

Written as:

```
RewriteRule ^name/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([A-Z])/?$ name.php?category=$1&gender=$2&alpha=$3
```

to get URL as: `http: //localhost/name/uk/girl/A`

But how do I rewrite a URL in `.htaccess` file if the URL is:

`http://localhost/name.php?**$category**=$origin&gender=$gen&alpha=$alphabet`

Now the "category" also becomes a variable `$category`

variable category varies as: country or religion or language or anything else.

Comment: Did you try something like: `RewriteRule ^name/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z]+)/([A-Z])/?$ name.php?$1=$2&gender=$3&alpha=$4`

Comment: thank u Mr. Condorcho your suggestion worked like a charm. It worked.

Comment: Awesome, glad to help.